# Dobbelt foreach function

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to import data from a JSON array to Google sheet. However, its a nested array which complexity exceeds my abilities.

This is My JSON (I have deleted irrelevant objects):

```
{"result":[
{"MyEnergyData_MarketDocument":{
    "TimeSeries"[{
        "Period":[{
            "Point":[
                {"position":"1","quantity":"0.489"},        
                {"position":"2","quantity":"7.57"},             
                {"position":"3","quantity":"0.131"}…] ETC
            "Point":[
                {"position":"1","quantity":"0.136"},
                {"position":"2","quantity":"0.131"},
                {"position":"3","quantity":"0.134"}…] ETC
            “Point” … ETC
```

This is my GAS code

```
var meterdatajson = Utilities.jsonParse(meterdata);
var meterdataArray = meterdatajson['result'];
var arrayProperties = [];
meterdataArray.forEach(function(el) {
  arrayProperties.push(
    el.MyEnergyData_MarketDocument.TimeSeries[0].Period[0].Point.map(p => [
      p.position,
      p.quantity
    ]));});

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Forbrug");
sheet.getRange(1, 1, arrayProperties.length, arrayProperties[0].length).setValues(arrayProperties);
```

Secondly, when the “quantity” gets imported to sheets, it converts to a date. Makes no sense.

I have tried with a double "foreach" function. But regardless, I only get the first interval of "Point" and not the rest.
All the “position” and “quantity” need to be pushed to the same array in the same lever.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function dumpData() {
  let testData = {"result":[
                          {"MyEnergyData_MarketDocument":
                            { "TimeSeries":[
                              { "Period":[
                                { "Point":[
                                  {"position":"1","quantity":"0.489"},        
                                  {"position":"2","quantity":"7.57"},             
                                  {"position":"3","quantity":"0.131"}]
                                },
                                { "Point":[
                                  {"position":"1","quantity":"0.136"},
                                  {"position":"2","quantity":"0.131"},
                                  {"position":"3","quantity":"0.134"}]
                                }
                              ]
                              }
                            ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      };
  let arrayProperties = [];
  let period = testData.result[0].MyEnergyData_MarketDocument.TimeSeries[0].Period.map( point => {
      point.Point.forEach( position => arrayProperties.push([position.position,position.quantity]));
    }
  );
  console.log(arrayProperties);
}
```

```
8:03:34 AM  Notice  Execution started
8:03:35 AM  Info    [ [ '1', '0.489' ],
  [ '2', '7.57' ],
  [ '3', '0.131' ],
  [ '1', '0.136' ],
  [ '2', '0.131' ],
  [ '3', '0.134' ] ]
8:03:35 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```